# given N disjoint triangles in 2D space, discover which one contains a given point without iterating through everyone

Tags: algorithm, geometry

Pretty straightforward: given **N** triangles **T1, ... ,Tn** and a point **P**, what is the best approach to find an **i** such that **P** is inside **Ti**?

PS: Don't know if this is important, but the triangles are disposed as if they were part of the map of a country (for example, get any country and draw it only with triangles, thats how the given triangles should be placed like).

Comment: Do you have control over the data-structure that the triangles are in? Because your question makes it sound like you're just given an array of triangles in no particular order, but in that case you'd *obviously* need to iterate over all of them in order to find any specific one.

Comment: no, but if necessary, I'm allowed to sort them or insert them into a data structure in the beginning

Comment: That doesn't help, because any mechanism for sorting/structuring/etc. will have to iterate over all of them. Or do you mean that you'll be performing this search for the same set of triangles and *many* points P? In that case, I think I'd count that as "yes", you can reorganize the triangles before you begin the searches.

Comment: @Daniel: you must answer explicitly. Is there a single point or can you amortize preprocessing over a large number of points ?

Comment: there will be a single point

Answer (score 2):

If preprocessing is an option, you can consider inserting your triangles in an R-tree.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree

---

**Update:**

If there is a single point, there is no shortcut. Exhaustive comparison is mandated. Otherwise the algorithm could "guess" the position of some triangles without even looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of Sweepline algorithm. You need to order triangles from their left to right co-ordinates.

Make a Minpriority queue and put all triangles(co-ordinates , left and right, so each trinangle will be inserted twice, the first point is begin point(x-min) and the second point is end point(x-max)) in priotity queue and the co-ordinates of point also.

**Remove the first co-ordinate:**

if it is left point then put it in binary search tree along witht triangle whose co-ordinate is this.

If it is right co-ordinate then remove the triangle from the binarysearchtree.

If it is co-ordinates of point then the your point must lie in only those triangles who are in binarysearchtree.